# capturing group VS non-capturing group

Tags: regex

I tried to test the performance of capturing and non-capturing group of the regex.
By the way, there is very slightly different between the capturing group and the non-capturing group.
Is this result normal?

```
[root@Sensor ~]# ll -h sample.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21M Oct 20 23:01 sample.log

[root@Sensor ~]# time grep -ciP '(get|post).*' sample.log
20000

real    0m0.083s
user    0m0.070s
sys     0m0.010s

[root@Sensor ~]# time grep -ciP '(?:get|post).*' sample.log
20000

real    0m0.083s
user    0m0.077s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Comment: Non-capturing group takes a little less time than a capturing group since no text is saved in the buffer.

Comment: If you're looking to save time, get rid of the `.*`, because it will always match, and you are not capturing it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typically, non-capturing groups perform better than capturing groups, because they require less allocation of memory, and do not make a copy of the group match. However, there are three important caveats:

- The difference is typically very small for simple, short expressions with short matches.
- The act of starting a program like `grep` itself takes a significant amount of time and memory, and may overwhelm any small improvement gained by using non-capturing group(s).
- Some languages implement capturing and non-capturing groups in the same way, causing the latter to give no performance improvement.

Comment: Since you mention the load-time of the binary, you might want to mention that file I/O is fairly slow when compared to CPU speed as well. Hopefully, the whole file `sample.log` was in the OS's I/O cache during both of the invocations of `grep`.

Answer (score 5):

If use a lot of the capturing group.
The difference seems to be more.

Thanks everyone.:)

```
[root@Sensor ~]# time grep -ciP "(get|post)\s[^\s]+" sample.log
20000

real    0m0.057s
user    0m0.051s
sys     0m0.005s
[root@Sensor ~]# time grep -ciP "(?:get|post)\s[^\s]+" sample.log
20000

real    0m0.061s
user    0m0.053s
sys     0m0.006s
[root@Sensor ~]# time grep -ciP "(get|post)\s[^\s]+(get|post)" sample.log
1880

real    0m0.839s
user    0m0.833s
sys     0m0.005s
[root@Sensor ~]# time grep -ciP "(?:get|post)\s[^\s]+(?:get|post)" sample.log
1880

real    0m0.744s
user    0m0.741s
sys     0m0.003s
```