# Performance optimizing a regex (regular expression) that matches a specific URL schema

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, optimization, pattern-matching

I am working on optimizing a regex (regular expression) that will match the following URL schema:

`protocol://anything1/folder/index.html[?param=anything2]`

where items in brackets are optional, and `anything1` and `anything2` can each be sequences of any characters.  **Everything else is static literals.**

If it matters, `anything1` will range in length from 36 to 48 characters, and `anything2` will range in length from 5 to 40 characters.  The regex does not need to validate any of this.

**Importantly, both `anything1` and `anything2` can include forward slashes.**

There are no issues if the regex requires `anything1` or `anything2` to be at least 1 character, as it always will be, but as performance is most important, I'm fine if it matches 0 or 1+ characters for `anything1` and/or `anything2`.

The regex is only used for matching, and not for parsing.  Captured groups are not used elsewhere in the code.

***Most importantly,*** I would like the regex to be as efficient (in regards to speed) as possible.

So far, I have:

`^protocol://.+/folder/index\.html($|\?param=.+)`

The regex ***must match the entire string, and not just part of it***.

The regex engine is the one used internally by Firefox for its CSS engine (which I believe is the same as their JavaScript regex engine).

My regex works as expected, and I'm asking if it can be further optimized for performance.

Comment: Depending on `anything1` expected length in _your_ specific cases, you might consider making the corresponding `.+` part lazy (with `?` modifier). But as for 'one-size-fits-all' scenario it seems to be a decent choice.

Comment: Should the first `.+` be able to match a dot or a space?

Comment: @raina77ow Thank you for your comment.  `anything1` will be a standard UUID (32 hex digits, plus 4 dashes), although it does not require any validation by the regex (validated elsewhere).

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for mentioning that.  Yes, it's fine if `anything1` matches a dot or a space.  `anything1` and `anything2` are validated elsewhere before hitting the regex.

Comment: If you want to have your regex optimised, could you publish it? For I am not sure that `^protocol://.+/folder/index\.html($|\?param=.+)` is literally the regex you work with. Does it really have `protocol` in it? Also, what do you want to achieve with your regex? Only matching, or parsing?

Comment: If `anything1` can be a uuid which does not have to be validated you might use a negated character class. If you don't need the capturing group at the end you can make it non capturing. But I don't know if firefox optimizes the patterns when executed, so you would have to performance test it. `^protocol://[^\/\s]+/folder/index\.html(?:\?param=.+)?$`

Comment: @AlexanderMashin Thank you for your interest.  The regex published above is literally the regex I wrote, just with the literals changed to make it much easier to read.  Matching is the only function of this regex (no parsing).

Comment: @Thefourthbird After reading your comment above, I think it will make a good answer.  I do not need the contents of any captured groups.  Does making a group non-capturing improve its performance?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Just FYI, since validation is handled elsewhere, your proposed regex can be simplified by removing `\s`.

Comment: There are some post about capturing groups and performance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243292/capturing-group-vs-non-capturing-group or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444807/why-is-regex-search-slower-with-capturing-groups-in-python Could not yet find if it also applies to Firefox though. Maybe somebody else knows..

Comment: Actually, upon reading it again, I don't think your proposal would quite meet the specified schema.  Technically, the spec allows `anything1` to include a forward-slash.  I'm going to take a look at some of the code to see if that ever happens, but I think it does. For example: `protocol://UUID/folderxyz/folder/index.html`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I have updated the question to answer your questions and provide additional details, such as the fact that `anything1` can include forward slashes.

Comment: Then you might opt to match the range from 36 to 48 chars `^protocol://.{36,48}/folder/index\.html(?:\?param=.+)?$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Interesting idea!  Would the `.{36,48}` be faster than `.+` in this situation?  It requires another 2 variables for the regex engine to check, but also allows a potentially earlier match fail point.  Also note that `protocol` is unique, and will not match 99+% of strings being passed to the regex.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I see 3 possible improvements you made to my regex: (1) adding a length range for `anything1`, (2) preventing capturing a group, (3) changing how `anything2` is processed.  If you write an answer explaining (in as much or as little detail as you prefer!) why those 3 changes each will likely improve performance, it will be an incredible (and most appreciated!) answer.

Comment: Do you mean the `file:` when you say protocol, or something else ? _http:_ and domain ?

Comment: @Maxt8r For this question, I literally mean the static string `protocol`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `^protocol://.+/folder/index\.html($|\?param=.+)`, you could make the pattern a bit more specific so there is less work for the engine:

```
^protocol://.{36,48}/folder/index\.html(?:\?param=.+)?$
```

A few recommendations could be

- Change the first `.+` to the known limit of 36-48 characters according to the comments.

  The `.+` will first match until the end of the string, then it starts backtracking to match `/` and the rest of the pattern.
  Knowing the range upfront might cut down on the backtracking.
- If you don't need the last group, you can turn it into an optional non capturing group so there is no group data to store.
  See for example 2 pages about why using capturing groups is slower than using non capturing groups.

  See [capturing group VS non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243292/capturing-group-vs-non-capturing-group) and [Why is regex search slower with capturing groups in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444807/why-is-regex-search-slower-with-capturing-groups-in-python).
- As an indication, you can see for example the difference in steps with less backtracking (with PCRE selected on regex101, the Javascript option does not yield any steps)

  [Original pattern](https://regex101.com/r/piI3OE/1) and [updated pattern](https://regex101.com/r/suI8jg/1)

I don't know if Firefox does optimization beforehand, so if you really want to be sure if there is a performance win, you would have to benchmark it in Firefox.

**Note** that the `.` can match any character except a newline (and will also match a space), which does not take any data structure into account.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer.  I'm reading it multiple times, as well as all the links you kindly provided.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try something along this lines:

`^protocol:\/\/[a-z\d-]+([^?]+)?\/folder\/index\.html(\?[^=&]+=[^&]+)?$`

Note the usage of early-failing character classes to prevent backtracking (you may want to add more characters to those `[^]`'s).

https://regex101.com/r/h3x5vH/2.

Comment: After looking at your proposal, I'm guessing that you think this will likely be faster due to the early-failing negative character classes.  Am I correct?  Note that `anything1` can include forward slashes, so some things will have to change.  BTW, the protocol is a custom protocol that will not match 99+% of strings passed to the regex.  Given that fact, will the regex I already wrote be just as fast as the one you proposed?

Comment: You can easily replace `https?` with `protocol`. If `anything1` can contain slashes, I see no reason to separate it from `folder` and `index` unless those are constants and are to be taken literally. If so, try something like `^protocol:\/\/[a-z\d-]+([^?]+)?\/folder\/index\.html(\?[^=&]+=[^&]+)?$`. I assume, there is a traditional domain name in your URL.

Comment: Thanks.  Correct, `folder` and `index` are constants and are to be taken literally.  What I'm wondering is, since `^protocol` will almost always (99+%) generate a match fail, does anything after it really matter much?  Or even with the caret before `protocol`, can the regex after `^protocol` still make a substantial performance difference?

Comment: I think that a caret before `protocol` is important. I think that without it, re regex engine will consume the whole line before giving up. And if most of your strings do not begin with `^protocol` and you are OK with few false positives, you can drop the rest altogether, although it doesn't cost anything after the regex is compiled.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful feedback!